# display a list of books with the highest points where active is true

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I a display of a list of books. The books have points where the book with the highest number of points is to appear on top sorted in descending. Below is the structure of the book table

```
books.php
id | name | points | active
1  | xyz  | 5      | true
2  | foo  | 4      | true
3  | doo  | 6      | false
```

The goal is the books with the highest point remains on top. If the books have same points let it just sort in desc order.

Here is my controller snippets

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxxBundle:Books')->findBy(['active' => true], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

please how can I make the highest points be the first on the list from descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. As parameters of findBy are arrays, you can specify multiples ordering rules:

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxxBundle:Books')->findBy(['active' => true], ['points' => 'DESC', 'id' => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: yeah, that means that xyz should come first because it has the highest points. is that what your answer does

Comment: Yes xyz will come first.

Answer (score 1):

Just sorting by points does not work?

```
   $restresults = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('xxxBundle:Books')
                        ->findBy(
                            ['active' => true],
                            ['points' => 'DESC']
                        );
```